# why Xamarin ios with minimum ios 8.0 app not installing in ios 15

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created xamarin forms ios app with Minimum System version 8.0
while installing it on device i am getting an error saying:-

"The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS".

The device is having iOS 15.

can anyone suggest me what update i need to do in my project to make it work properly in any iOS version.

[I have attached the error while installing on iphone iOS 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTRII.jpg)

Your Suggestion will be great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build it with Xcode 13 for it to run on iOS 15. Is that an Enterprise app?

Comment: i am creating the ipa through building the project in release mode, i am not archiving it to publish just build project and get ipa in project's bin folder.

Comment: I am using xcode 12 and the same issue persist in ios 14 and below.

Comment: Did you try use Xcode13 and run in ios15?

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
building project with xcode 13 worked for ios 15